# Inline citation with BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm writing my graduation project in TeX, using a model from my university, which uses BibTeX and natbib for citations. The problem I'm trying to solve is: how to make inline citations like `Author (year)`?

By using `\citet{}` I achieved `AUTHOR (year)`, but I wished to make it only first-letter-capitalized instead of all-caps.

Unfortunately, I'm looking for solutions which involve only BibTeX and natbib, since I can't change to BibLaTeX due to model constraints.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The capitalization (or lack thereof) of authors' names in citations is not determined by `natbib` directly but, rather, by the bibliography style you employ. (Incidentally, I'm guessing that the authors' names are begin typeset in small-caps, not regular-caps, letters. Is this hunch correct?) Which bibliography style are you using?

Comment: @Mico I'm using `\bibliographystyle{abnt}`. May this style be defined by the model I'm using?

Comment: Are you also using the `abntcite` package and/or one of the `abntex` document classes? (If so, which ones?) Please advise.

Comment: @Mico nope, this package is absolutely not here.

Comment: I can't find a file named `abnt.bst` anywhere on the CTAN. Could you give an indication where it might be obtained from?

Comment: @Mico here: http://www.if.ufrgs.br/hadrons/abnt/abnt.bst

Comment: I can't reproduce the problems you're describing. In fact, I get a warning from `natbib` that the bibliography style (`abnt`) in incompatible with "authoryear"-style citations. I can generate numeric-style citations just fine (and get uppercased authors' names in the references), but authoryear-style citations aren't working. Please consider posting a MWE (minimum working example) that shows your document's basic citation-related setup. I have a feeling that some important information related to the problem at hand is still missing.

Comment: @Mico due to the model I'm using making a MWE is difficult since it will lack the "minimum" part. I'm gonna try talking to someone about this problem and then post my solution here.

Comment: As it stands this question and indeed the answer fall into the 'unclear' category as there is not enough info to make it reproducible. As such, I'm minded to close: please edit to improve (think of other users).

Comment: @JosephWright I thought it was a problem with BibTeX due to my inexperience with TeX, but it turned out to be a problem with the model provided by my university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to people that made the model I was using, I discovered I can change it by changing the related `.bst` file.

Comment: Please consider making this answer a bit more informative by indicating *which* alternative bibliography style you chose.

Comment: I didn't - I just changed my text to fit in the default bibliography style (authors last name separated by ;, all caps).